# hello i want to make a gui that check if a player has a badge and do visible a frame how can i do it?

Tags: lua, roblox

i want to make a gui that check if a player has a badge and do visible a frame but idk how to do it i'm new whit roblox studio ayone can help me?

```
local Players = game:GetService("Players")
local ImageLabel = script.Parent

local badgeId = 2130266538 -- Badge ID

local function onPlayerAdded(player)

    local success, hasBadge = pcall(function()
        return BadgeService:UserHasBadgeAsync(player.UserId, badgeId)
    end)


    if not success then
        warn("Error while checking if player has badge!")
        return
    end
    
    if hasBadge == true then 
        ImageLabel.Visible= true end
    
end


Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(onPlayerAdded)
```

idk what is wrong, it dont show the imagelabel when you have the badge

Comment: Are there any errors in the output?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot this i think

```
local BadgeService = game:GetService("BadgeService")
```

place it in the function

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).